# Not able to click on Login button using selenium while executing a test script

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

After giving Xpath for Login,not able to click on Login button when I test script through selenium.
Scenario -
•   Login into application by giving username and password.

```
public class Myclass {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\karokiaswamy\\Documents\\Selenium_installation\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\autoit\\HandleAuth.exe");
     driver.get("Application URL");
   //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\autoit\\HandleAuth.exe");
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.get("Application URL");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")).clear();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys("testtrack");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).clear();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("password01");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/button")).clear();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(" ");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("///button[@class ='btnSmall btnGreen']")).click();
   //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/button")).click()
  }
}
```

Comment: copy your login page html if possible

Comment: Can you provide more information: 1. What are you doing through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\autoit\\HandleAuth.exe");` ? 2. Can you provide a valid credentials for the site?

Comment: @ venkatasiva - Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\autoit\\HandleAuth.exe") is used to give username and password for Authentication alert before navigating to application.

Comment: @ venkatasiva - For security reason I cant give the application URL and authentication credentials. Please try to give the solution by seeing above code.

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: @aknathan As username, password & Ok button all of them are on windows authentication dialog box, you need to provide username, password and also click on "Ok" button with AutoIT.

Comment: @ venkatasiva - this is the error message I got.
line 3686: unreachable code after return statement
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you get an exception after clicking login button.
If you do you can click with javascript as:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```